# Получить самую большую цифру в числе

Tags: python

```
def func(num):
    max = 0
    for i in range(num):
        if i > max:
            max = i
    return (max)


print(func(67124))
```

Comment: Советую не использовать имя `max`, Вы так переопределяете [стандартную функцию `max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max).

Comment: Дарья Лазарева  Если какой-то из ответов помог вам, то не забудьте пометить этот ответ как правильный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно привести число к строке, чтобы на каждой итерации получить отдельную цифру.

***Пример:***

```py
def f(num):
    m = 0
    for n in str(num):
        if int(n) > m:
            m = int(n)
    return m
```

Comment: Спасибо! С  int  не догадалась почему-то!(((

Answer (score 4):

Можно использовать функцию [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) для строкового представления числа.

***Пример:***

```py
def f(num):
    return int(max(str(num)))
```

Цифры будут сравниваться на основе [ASCII](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) кода их символьного представления. Это возможно, потому что их коды находятся последовательно от меньшего к большему (48-57).

Answer (score 3):

способ 1:

```
def f(num):
    return max(map(int, str(num)))
```

способ 2:

```
def f(num):
    res = 0
    while num != 0:
      res = max(res, num % 10)
      num //= 10
    return res
```

способ 3:

```
def f(num):
  return int(sorted(str(num))[-1])
```

способ 3.5:

```
def f(num):
  return int(list(set(str(num)))[-1])
```